# How can I login a user in my flask web app when they have signed up?

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a book review web app in flask using PostgreSQL database. However, I am stuck on how to login a user and track their session and once a user logs-in he must be taken to a html page where he can search for a book and add a review. I know we can use `sessions` in flask. But, I am really confused on how do I do it.

`application.py`

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["GET","POST"])
def signin():
    if request.method=="GET":
        session["user_id"] = user_id     #ERROR ON THIS LINE
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        return render_template("search.html")
```

My `users` table in the database which stores the username,password and user_id

```
 Table "public.users"
  Column  |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 username | character varying(30) |           | not null | ''::character varying
 password | character varying(30) |           | not null | ''::character varying
 user_id  | integer               |           | not null | nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are getting the `user_id` variable from, but the syntax for using sessions is correct. Instead of assigning the `session["user_id"]` in a GET request, you can assign it after a successful post like this:

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["GET","POST"])
def signin():
    if request.method=="GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        # assuming you have an html form with <input type="text" name="username"> and <input type="password" name="password"> 
        username = request.form.get("username") # from your login form
        password = request.form.get("password") 
        # verify the username and password here to see if they are in the database then return the id of the person 
        # if the id is an integer then you can do this:
        session["user_id"] = user_id # from the database
        #instead of using the same endpoint, I'd suggest redirecting to a different endpoint that renders the search.html while checking the session for the userid
        return redirect(url_for("search"))


@app.route("/search")
def search():
  if "user_id" in session:
      return render_template("search.html")
  else:
      return redirect(url_for("signin"))
```

Comment: `user_id = db.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users where username = :username",{"username":username})`    But, this gives me an error `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`. I think the problem is with the above code.

Comment: Can you tell me what framework or library you are using to query the database?

Comment: PostgreSQL database for storing users and SQLalchemy in flask.

Comment: Unless there is an edit  to your database, the code should execute fine. However, the problem is that you are trying to assign the `user_id` which is an integer to a sqlalchemy ResultProxy. 

Try editing it in this way:

`result = db.execute('select user_id from users where username = :username', {'username':username})

user_id = result.first()[0]`

If there is another problem it should be the `username` variable or the database connection. That's what I can see as the source of problems in this scenario.